# Firebase query ordering by child not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem**

I'm trying to query a list of objects by createionDate. For some reason it will not fetch objects in a ascending order.

**My data structure**

[image]

**my code**

```
func fetchQuest() {
        
        guard let uid = selectedUID else {return}
        
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("questsByUID").child(uid)
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "CreationDate")
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            
            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
            dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
                
                guard let dictionary = value as? [String : Any] else {return}
                let quest = Quest(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
                quest.questID = key
                print("quest name is: ", quest.questName)
                self.board.append(quest)
                
            })
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }) { (err) in
            print("unable to fetch quest:", err)
        }
    }
```

**My Model**

```
class Quest {

var questID = ""
let questName: String
let creatorUID: String
let creationDate: Date

init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.questName = dictionary["questName"] as? String ?? ""
    self.creatorUID = uid
    let secondsFrom1970 = dictionary["creationDate"] as? Double ?? 0
    self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
}}
```

**console output**

quest name is:  Third quest

quest name is:  2nd quest

quest name is:  4th quest from Ada

quest name is:  Ada’s first quest

Answer (score 3):

Given that the Firebase database is *case sensitive*, try changing your query from:

```
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "CreationDate")
```

to:

```
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")
```

Your `Quest` model class is already using the correct spelling.

**Update**. As mentioned by the other answer, a dictionary is *not* order preserving. As such, you should be using `FIRDataSnapshot.children` iterator instead. For instance:

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { 
    (snapshots) in
    for child in snapshots.children {
        let snapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        let quest = Quest(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
        quest.questID = snapshot.key
        ...
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm still using the same `observeSingleEvent` as your original code does.

Comment: the output is still not in ascending order. it seem random

Comment: @JeffreyChang You are right! Found another bug... please check the updated answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think order is different because dictionary is an unordered collection of key-value pairs. So I think since you want to get the values in ordered manner, you can use eventType of `.childAdded` because according to documentation :

> Unlike value which returns the entire contents of the location,
>   childAdded is triggered once for each existing child and then again
>   every time a new child is added to the specified path

so you can modify your code like this:

1. First as the other answer states that change `CreationDate` to `creationDate`
2. Second use `.childAdded` instead of `.value` as the event type.

`let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")
        query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in...`

Comment: after switching to .childAdded, firebase will only fetch 1 object instead of entire list. i assume it's because of this line .observeSingleEvent. sorry for the late reply

Comment: @JeffreyChang you can use `observe` instead of `observeSingleEvent` , please check the updated answer